# How do I calculate outstanding balance for product inventory?

Tags: views

I have two content types, **Product In** and **Product Out**.
Content types **Product In** has the *title* as *Product Code*, and a field as *Model*.
The content type **Product Out** has a node reference (*Product Code*) to **Product In**, and a field as *Customer Name*.

I have a view, Product Inventory, with aggregation on. I have two fields:

- *Total Product In* (By counting Content types **Product In**'s title)
- *Total Product Out* (By counting Content types **Product Out**'s title)

How can I get the outstanding balance which I have inside my inventory?

Answer (score 0):

[Balance Tracker](https://drupal.org/project/balance_tracker) creates a balance sheet to display account credits and debits belonging to users. It can be integrated with views.

> It also provides UI tools, Views integration, and an API to allow the
>   site administrators or other modules to credit or debit a user's
>   account. This is intended for any website or service which credits
>   users for accounts, sales, or other activities, and needs to track
>   payouts.

I'm not using this before. Hope it helps you!!!